# Configuring data source URL in Spring without XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a simple Web MVC application using Spring Boot that communicates with a database; the DB is H2 and has been in memory until now. I want to change that, and thus use a `jdbc:h2:file:...` URL.

Up until now, I have not needed to add any XML to configure my application, and I'd prefer it to stay that way if possible. But I can't figure out how to specify a different JDBC URL. I obtained and inspected the data source by passing it to an `@Bean` method:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@745e6f01{ConnectionPool[
defaultAutoCommit=null; 
defaultReadOnly=null; 
defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; 
defaultCatalog=null; 
driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; 
maxActive=100; 
maxIdle=100; 
minIdle=10; 
initialSize=10; 
maxWait=30000; 
testOnBorrow=false; 
testOnReturn=false; 
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; 
numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; 
testWhileIdle=false; 
testOnConnect=false; 
password=********; 
url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; 
username=sa; 
validationQuery=null; 
validationQueryTimeout=-1; 
validatorClassName=null; 
validationInterval=30000; 
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; 
removeAbandoned=false; 
removeAbandonedTimeout=60; 
logAbandoned=false; 
connectionProperties=null; 
initSQL=null; 
jdbcInterceptors=null; 
jmxEnabled=true; 
fairQueue=true; 
useEquals=true; 
abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; 
maxAge=0; 
useLock=false; 
dataSource=null; 
dataSourceJNDI=null; 
suspectTimeout=0; 
alternateUsernameAllowed=false; 
commitOnReturn=false; 
rollbackOnReturn=false; 
useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; 
logValidationErrors=false; 
propagateInterruptState=false; 
ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; 
}
```

(newlines mine)

The setup of that bean seems rather intricate, so I want to interfere with it as little as possible - just replace the default JDBC URL.

**How can I configure individual properties for Spring to create the datasource?** Preferably in Java, but if there is a concise XML way I'm happy as well. I just want to avoid adding 100 lines of boilerplate for something equivalent to `url=...`

Comment: Add `spring.datasource.url` to the `application.properties`, restart and be done. For a list of properties see the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: seems I didn't use the right search terms... thanks! If you make this an answer, I'll accept it. By the way, I also had to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` to avoid `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Comment: @M.Deinum forgot to tag you

Comment: (also related: the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property is `create-drop` by default. To keep the data, change it to `update` for example)

Comment: set `spring.jpa.database-platform` instead of `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataSource` is auto configured by Spring Boot for you. To influence how and what there are several properties you can set. Those are prefixed with `spring.datasource`, for a list take a look at the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for a full list.

In your case simply add the following to the `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:...
```

This will tell Spring Boot to use this URL instead of the default.

As H2 is considered an in-memory database and not a regular database, when using JPA this will lead to your database to be dropped when the application is stopped. To fix this simply add the following

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

To specify a dialect simply add the following

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

or even simpler

```
spring.jpa.database=H2
```